# Error when create replication user with mysql role in ansible

Tags: mysql, ansible, replication

I'm having problems when use **geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql**

The error is:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'password'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/root/.ansible/roles/geerlingguy.mysql/tasks/replication.yml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Ensure replication user exists on master.\n ^ here\n"}
```

My **vars/main.yml :**

```
mysql_bind_address: '0.0.0.0'
mysql_server_id: "1"
mysql_max_binlog_size: "100M"
mysql_binlog_format: "ROW"
mysql_expire_logs_days: "10"
mysql_replication_role: 'master'
mysql_replication_master: 'ip'
mysql_replication_user:
        - name: slave01
          password: pass1
          priv: "*.*:REPLICATION SLAVE"
        - name: slave02
          password: pass2
          priv: "*.*:REPLICATION SLAVE"
```

I'm using an existing role, where you can see a similar example: https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql#example-playbook

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an array of objects according to yaml. Remove the '-' and indent everything to 0 spaces:

```
name: asddad
password: asdasd
host: asdasd
priv: asdasd
```

Comment: Right, but that's exactly what I need if I'm not wrong. I have completed a bit more the main.yml file. Answer with more information below

Comment: Include what you wrote as an answer as an edit to your post